# What is the difference between functionalisation and passivation?

Tags: terminology, nanoscience

I know the basic principle of functionalisation and passivation is to add Ligands to the surface of nano particles which can  limit the growth of nano-crystals in fabrication and improve proprieties of the particle. But what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Perhaps more an English usage question... I would say 'functionalize' works for adding any kind of groups, while 'passivate' adds groups that reduce or eliminate surface reactivity. So, passivation is a subset of functionalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passivation is a process by which a surface is rendered chemically nonreactive. For example, aluminum can be made corrosion-resistant to sea water exposure by growing a conformal aluminum oxide coating on it.

Functionalization is a process by which a surface can be given different chemical characteristics by applying a monolayer of a different element or some molecular species. For example, a gold surface can be made nonwetting to aqueous solutions by applying a self-assembling monolayer of C-16thiol.